# error: package com.firebase.ui.database does not exist

Tags: java, android, firebase

I get this error

```
 error: package com.firebase.ui.database does not exist
```

Also i used this package

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
```

But cannot resolve symbol 'ui'

```
cannot resolve symbol 'ui'
```

I am using this sdk version

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    }
```

I use this  FirebaseUI libraries

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

Comment: Post your entire build.gradle files for app and project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your firebase ui dependency according to your firebase dependency, see this list

[image]

Comment: Awesome, please mark the correct answer if you dont mind

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare supported version number of Firebase UI libraries with Firebase/Play Services Version.

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
```

To learn more see https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-the-library-in-your-android-app